# Restructure (filter&flatten) each row of an array

Tags: php, arrays

Well, I have this array `$city` :

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => fr
                [1] => paris
                [2] => a8
            )

        [1] => 0
        [2] => 116729
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => fr
                [1] => marseille
                [2] => b8
            )

        [1] => 0
        [2] => 12898
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => fr
                [1] => lyon
                [2] => b9
            )

        [1] => 0
        [2] => 8608
    )
```

And so on...
I'm trying to transform it to :

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => fr
        [1] => paris
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 116729
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => fr
        [1] => marseille
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 12898
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => fr
        [1] => lyon
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 8608
    )
```

And here's how i do it :

```
foreach ($city as $key => $value){
$city[$key][0] = $city[$key][0][0];
array_splice( $city[$key], 1, 0, $city[$key][0][1] );
 }
```

But the issue here is that the result array :

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => fr
        [1] => r
        [2] => 0
        [5] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => fr
        [1] => r
        [2] => 0
        [5] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => fr
        [1] => r
        [2] => 0
        [5] => 0
    )
```

What is the error in my code and can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_map` instead of `foreach`:

```
$result = array_map(
    function ($v) { return array_merge(array_slice($v[0], 0, 2), array_slice($v, 1)); },
    $array
);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/doV4S0)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
foreach($city as $key => $value) {
    $city[$key] = [
        $value[0][0], //fr
        $value[0][1], //lyon
        $value[1], //0
        $value[2], //8608
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After you do:

```
$city[$key][0] = $city[$key][0][0];
```

you can't reference the original `$city[$key][0]` because you've replaced it. The solution is to save it in a variable first:

```
foreach ($city as $key => &$value){
    $subarray = $value[0];
    $value[0] = $subarray[0];
    array_splice($value, 1, 0, $subarray[1] );
 }
```

I've also used a reference to avoid having to repeat `$city[$key]` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (provided that your array is called `$new` in the example below):


```
    foreach ($item as $derp) {

        if (is_array($derp)) {
            foreach ($derp as $derrrrrr) {
                $d[$i][] = $derrrrrr;
            }
        } else {
            $d[$i][] = $derp;
        }
    }

    $i++;
}
?>
```

#### Returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => fr
            [1] => paris
            [2] => a8
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 11678
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => fr
            [1] => paris
            [2] => a8
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 11678
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => fr
            [1] => paris
            [2] => a8
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 11678
        )

)
```

#### EDIT

Use the below to ignore the index[2] in the first multi-dimensional array.

```
$d = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($new as $item) {

    foreach ($item as $derp) {

        if (is_array($derp)) {
            foreach ($derp as $key => $derrrrrr) {
                if ($key !== 2) {
                    $d[$i][] = $derrrrrr;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $d[$i][] = $derp;
        }
    }

    $i++;
}
```